# soap - Fix missing characters in a string

Tags: python, unicode, suds

While passing a text to a webserver I noticed that some unicodes are not passed to the webserver ( ' / \ and probaly more I don't know about)

And `string.decode('utf-8')` won't work because is doesn't work with strings. Any way to fix this?

I'm using suds-jurko as a soup lib which is suds but updated for 3.x.

```
my_text = "I'm trying to do my best"
yoda_url = 'http://www.yodaspeak.co.uk/webservice/yodatalk.php?wsdl'
client  = Client(yoda_url)
yodish = client.service.yodaTalk(my_text)
print(yodish)
```

It get's printed as: My best, **im** trying to do.  Hmmmmmm..

While on the website it gets translated as: Trying to do my best, **I am**.  Yes, hmmm.

As you can se **I'm** sould e translated as **I am** but because the ' is not sending comes like **Im**

Comment: "passing ... to a webserver" is a bit unspecific. As the payload of a request, or as part of the URL/query string, something else? It's probably best if you show the code that does the passing.

Comment: Thanks.. I added the code and I put more details about my problem.

Comment: What makes you so sure that the characters aren't sent, rather than being lost in the translation process? It could be that the browser-based interface uses a slightly different algorithm than the API-based one, eg. with respect to preprocessing.

Comment: I don't really know... i just saw that they are not changed and when I checked the website everything was good .. Also searched about and I found that sometimes with webservices that Unicode characters are not send .. I thought maybe is the sane thing with ASCII characters

Comment: Every character is a Unicode character. The ones you are missing are also ASCII characters.

Comment: Ik.. I tried anything I could to fix it.. but I might try to replace the Im with I'm after the translated text comes back... maye I could use an autocorrect library